# How to change the color of status bar when gradient is applied to navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to apply gradient color on navigation bar. I applied that but the status bar color is not changing. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code for implementing the gradient color:

```
let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 90/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 44/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 64)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: Please check my answer and reply..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:-20, width:375, height:64)
```

### output:

[image]

### In Swift3:

```
        let colorTop = UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 90/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 44/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:-20, width:375, height:64)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: Welcome Dupinder

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer) with

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.sublayers?.insert(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Added image after building with above code

[image]