# How to apply the gradient applied in UINavigationBar to the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom navigation bar class where I can update its color, font and title. I was able to implement the gradient to my UINavigationBar but the status bar stays in white color?

I know there's a solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120027/how-to-change-the-color-of-status-bar-when-gradient-is-applied-to-navigation-bar) but I'm not using a UINavigationController, just a UINavigationBar to my UIViewController.

I've implemented a UINavigationBarDelegate `position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition` and returned `topAttached` but the status bar is still on white color. Any idea what could be the solution for this?

Comment: Isnt it same? The other answer just point to the navigationBar in navigationController, you can just remove the `navigationController?.` part

Comment: Nope @Tj3n, it doesn't work on my part if it's not on navigationController

Comment: Add your code for understand how you are doing @Rhenz